# What is the proper or best way to get data from ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

I have this `javascript` code with `ajax`.

```
$('#btnCart').click(function() {
    var pName = document.getElementById('prodName').value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        data: 'prdName='+pName,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#prod').html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

I want to get the value of `pName` to be returned on my php. Here's my code on my `index.php` side:

```
<?php 
    $prodName = $_GET['prdName'];
    echo $prodName;

 ?>
```

But it returns `Unidentified index: prdName`.

How can I get the value from ajax to my php? Please help...

Comment: no.. supposedly, the `prdName` is an index for `$prodName`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your PHP code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['prdName'])){
  $prodName = $_GET['prdName'];
  echo cartTable($prodName);
}
```

also some corrections in js:

```
$('#btnCart').click(function() {
    var pName = $('#prodName').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {prdName:pName},
        success: function(data) {
          $('#prod').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i think there's no need to check if the `$prodName` variable has a value or not because on the upper code, it says it couldn't identify the the index of `prdName` variable.

Comment: Anyway it should be checked. Above i made some corrections i think it will be helpful.

Comment: the `#prodName` is actually an id of a hidden input. so this code `var pName = $('#prodName').val();` will not return the value of that element

Comment: No you can get hidden input element values by using jquery code also.. no matter what type it is.

Comment: yeah... i missed to type echo rather than alert... lol
btw, it's still not working... i dont know why... tss

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['prdName'])){
 $prodName = $_GET['prdName'];
    echo $prodName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send the data as:

```
data: {prdName: pName},
```

Answer (score -1):

In index.php Get the prdName value from $_POST[] global array. 
to send data to index.php file add type type:'POST' in ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {'prdName': pName},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#prod').html(data);
    }
 });
```

or you can use $.post() method in jQuery

```
 $.post(
   'index.php',
   {'prdName='+pName}, 
   function(data) {
      $('#prod').html(data);
   }
 });
```

in index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['prdName']){
  $prodName = $_POST['prdName'];
  echo $prodName;
}
```